# SpringBoot - Logging environment value cannot be opened and will be ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I'm setting up the logging system for my SpringBoot application. But I constantly encounter the `Logging environment value 'resources/logback.xml' cannot be opened and will be ignored` warning.

My `application.properties` file includes `logging.config=resources/logback.xml` and I already put my `logback.xml` file under `resources` directory. My SpringBoot version is: `1.1.4.RELEASE`

What I have tried:

1. I have tested the absolute path and the problem still exists so I don't think it is the file path that causes the problem.
2. I have changed the permission of the file and it is 777, which is open to all. Therefore the permission shouldn't be the issue.

And then I checked the Java file that has the warning: `LoggingApplicationListener.java`

The code is as below:

```
// User specified configuration
if (environment.containsProperty("logging.config")) {
    String value = environment.getProperty("logging.config");
    try {
        ResourceUtils.getURL(value).openStream().close();
        system.initialize(value);
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Swallow exception and continue
    }
    this.logger.warn("Logging environment value '" + value + "' cannot be opened and will be ignored");
}
```

From the code, this warning is inevitable? However, the configuration is initialized successfully, although it says it ignored the configure.

Comment: when i checked the spring source code for 1.1.X i see its logging warn only if its unable to get the resource https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.1.x/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.java#L256

Comment: also try logging.config=classpath:logback.xml

Answer (score 1):

So yeah. First thing is I'm not sure why you are using 1.1.4 but that aside..This was essentially a bug in 1.1.4. If you move to 1.1.5, you'll see they updated the code..

```
  try {
       ResourceUtils.getURL(value).openStream().close();
       system.initialize(value);
  } catch (Exception var7) {
      this.logger.warn("Logging environment value '" + value + "' cannot be opened and will be ignored");
  }
```

Also, I believe the correct value is "classpath:logback.xml". This is because although you might be running on a local environment, where your file actually lives in some src/main/java/resources, when the application is compiled the resources are moved into the classpath (or where your classes reside).

Comment: A legacy project... Yes 1.1.5 fixed the bug and could you please help with clarifying what does 'classpath' here represents? My `logback.xml` is under 'src/main/resources' folder. Thanks!

Comment: @dibugger Updated my answer. Thanks for calling me out on that.